# Optimisation for reading contacts in listView?

Tags: java, android

I have code to read contacts, get name and number and put them in listView. Everything works but application read all contacts in the same moment. I guess that I have to read them on scroll move, but I don't now how, please help?
Thank you in advance, Wolf.

Here is my code:

ArrayList> mapa = new ArrayList>();

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);


        if(cur.getCount() > 0){
            while(cur.moveToNext()){
                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                if(Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){

                    final Cursor numCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "  = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                    for(numCur.moveToFirst(); !numCur.isAfterLast(); numCur.moveToNext()){

                        brTel = numCur.getString(numCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        ime = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                        tmpIme = new String[] {ime};

                        for(int i = 0; i < tmpIme.length; i++){

                            HashMap<String, String> imeMapa = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            imeMapa.put("imeLista", ime);
                            imeMapa.put("Mobilni", brTel);
                            mapa.add(imeMapa);

                        }

                    }
                    numCur.close();

                }

            } // While
        }

        SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mapa, R.layout.imenik, new String[] {"imeLista", "Mobilni"}, new int[] {R.id.tvImeImenik, R.id.tvSamoProba});
        lImenik.setAdapter(sa);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a SimpleCursorAdapter, after that the application should be fast enough. Or did I misunderstand?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);       
    final Cursor c = managedQuery(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                                new String[]{Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, 
                                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != ?", new String[] {"NULL"}, 
                                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME );

    String[] from = new String[] { android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.nativecontacts_entry_name };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rawlayout, c, from, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that after I try application on my phone where I have something like 700 contacts, I have to wait 15 seconds, and then I get all contacts in the listView.

Comment: I want that to go faster if is possible?

Comment: but your code is doing something that is not necessary: copying the contacts in the map. You can use directly the cursor